# Table griding HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to generate HTML table into PDF.

But I'm having trouble for gridding the table. I want to generate table like this:

[image]

I have this table from database:

[image]

Which is should fill this column:

[image]

and I have a second table from database like this:

[image]

which is should fill the rest of the columns except `keterangan` column.

I tried this code :

```
<table class="tbl" border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<tr style="height: 50px;">
    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 50%">Nomor</th>
    <th colspan="4">Pemberian entertaiment dan sejenisnya</th>
    <th colspan="4">Relasi usaha yang diberikan entertainment dan sejenisnya</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Keterangan</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Tanggal</th>
    <th>Alamat</th>
    <th>Jenis</th>
    <th>Jumlah</th>
    <th>Nama</th>
    <th>Posisi</th>
    <th>Nama Perusahaan</th>
    <th>Jenis Usaha</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->nomor?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->tanggal?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row->alamat?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->jenis?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->jumlah?>
    </td>
    <?php
            foreach ($list->result() as $data){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->nama?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->posisi?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->nama_perusahan?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->jenis_usaha?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <td>
            <?PHP echo $row->keterangan?>
        </td>
</tr>
```

but this is the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table class="tbl" border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<tr style="height: 50px;">
    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 50%">Nomor</th>
    <th colspan="4">Pemberian entertaiment dan sejenisnya</th>
    <th colspan="4">Relasi usaha yang diberikan entertainment dan sejenisnya</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Keterangan</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Tanggal</th>
    <th>Alamat</th>
    <th>Jenis</th>
    <th>Jumlah</th>
    <th>Nama</th>
    <th>Posisi</th>
    <th>Nama Perusahaan</th>
    <th>Jenis Usaha</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->nomor?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->tanggal?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row->alamat?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->jenis?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?PHP echo $row->jumlah?>
    </td>
    <?php
            foreach ($list->result() as $data){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->nama?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->posisi?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->nama_perusahan?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?PHP echo $data->jenis_usaha?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <td>
            <?PHP echo $row->keterangan?>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Note the extra columns are added inside the loop to enable it to line up with you headers.

Comment: almost sir, i edited the result image on the post from the result you give,
thank you,
in the last row of the table it has `keterangan` coloumn data, its showing but not in the place.

Comment: Well, where do you want that column to appear, and how many times?

Comment: i move the coloumn to the 2nd row, thank you for your help.